# smtp connection errors when trying to connect to a custom email/domain

Tags: email, smtp, vercel, google-workspace, next-auth

I have a custom email address that is hosted via google suite that I am trying to connect to via smtp.

```
# Email

EMAIL_SERVER="smtp://spalmer:PASSWORD@smtp.ideally.place:587"
EMAIL_FROM="spalmer@ideally.place
```

But it just times out with the error below:

```
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_EMAIL_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_email_error connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.xx:587 {
  error: {
    message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.xx:587',
    stack: 'Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.xx:587\n' +
      '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)',
    name: 'Error'
  },
  providerId: 'email',
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx.xx:587'
}
```

I think I am sending the wrong server info because everything works fine when I just use my regular google email address. Like below

```
# Email

EMAIL_SERVER="smtp://palmer.simond:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com:587"
EMAIL_FROM="palmer.simond@gmail.com"
```

My `@ideally.place` is hosted by google but the web site ([www.ideally.place](http://www.ideally.place)) is hosted by Vercel if that makes a difference.
I have setup App Passwords on both, using the generated Passwords.
Do I need to setup a smtp relay service with Google Workspaces?